# Dropbox API - updating file

Tags: dropbox

I'm new to the Dropbox API and I'm trying to figure out if I can manage large file (1-2 Gb) updates without having to copy over the whole file.

Something similar to the initial chunked upload. I'd like a way to say, here's a chunk of this file, starting at offset `XXXX` and here's the new content. And send only 100Kb or 1Mb, but not the whole file over!

I'm surprised nobody needs something like that, since once you upload a large file, which is pretty easy to do with the chunked upload, one would still have an issue if the file needed updating. Especially if the updates are small!

Anyway, all feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's very much incremental sync. There's a free one doing this, by the name of OpenVCDiff. But when it comes to dropbox API, I don't know - I found your post when I was searching for dropbox here within SO.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't support any sort of incremental update.